# SDL_event list getting long and messy?

Tags: c++, events, sdl

What is a good way of doing SDL event handling?
You usually have the:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    //Handles all the events when in the menu screen...
    eventsMenu(event);
}
```

Problem is, when you get going with a game, there's usually a mess of a list of controls that you can do, like up and down detetion for many different keys. And I'm wondering weither the method I'm using is efficient and clean. Or if I should approach it diffrently...

I have a function pointer in the mainLoop, that can be assigned to quickly change how the events will be handled. (Say I swap to another function, and it will use those events)
However, I think the list of events get messy anyways, so I tried adding regions to break it up. Is that a good idea? And yeah, just want some input if I'm on the right path to a readable code.

```
void Window::eventsMenu(SDL_Event event) {
    switch (event.type) {
        #pragma region "Button Down"
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: {
            //printf("Mouse button down!\n");
            glClearColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1);
            if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
                mouseButtonLeft = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        #pragma endregion;
        #pragma region "Button Up"
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP: {
            //printf("Mouse button up!\n");
            glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
            if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
                mouseButtonLeft = false;
            }
            break;
        }
        #pragma endregion;
        #pragma region "Mouse Motion"
        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION: {
            //printf("Mouse moved!\n");
            if (mouseButtonLeft) {
                rotX += event.motion.xrel;
                rotY += event.motion.yrel;
            }
            break;
        }
        #pragma endregion;
        #pragma region "Mouse Wheel"
        case SDL_MOUSEWHEEL: {
            if (event.wheel.y != 0) {
                musicVolume += ((event.wheel.y > 0) ? 1 : -1);
                if (musicVolume > 100) {
                    musicVolume = 100;
                }
                else if (musicVolume < 0) {
                    musicVolume = 0;
                }
                Mix_VolumeMusic(musicVolume);
                printf("Volume: %i%c\n", musicVolume, '%');
            }

            if (event.wheel.y > 0) {
                //printf("Scroll forward!\n");
            }
            else {
                //printf("Scroll backward!\n");
            }
            break;
        }
        #pragma endregion;
        #pragma region "Key Down"
        case SDL_KEYDOWN: {
            printf("Button [%s] pressed\n", SDL_GetKeyName(event.key.keysym.sym));
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                case SDLK_1: {
                    Mix_PlayChannel(-1, sound1, 0);
                    break;
                }
                case SDLK_2: {
                    Mix_PlayChannel(-1, sound2, 0);
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        #pragma endregion;
        case SDL_QUIT: {
            running = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try codereview stackexchange. Personally I would loop events only once per frame and then use the data collected whenever neaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions :

Remove the braces ( `{` and `}` ) around the `case` labels. You don't need them unless you need a new stack.

---

My second suggestion is to split things into function. Even if it will only be called from within `switch`. Putting things into several functions helps makes the code easier to read and understand.

So for instance :

```
case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    HandeMouseButton( event );
    break;

void HandeMouseButton( const SDL_Event &event )
{
    if ( event.type ==  MOUSEBUTTONDOWN )
    {
        glClearColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1);
        if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
            mouseButtonLeft = true;
    }
    else if ( event.type ==  MOUSEBUTTONUP )
         glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
         if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
             mouseButtonLeft = false;
         }
    }
}
```

---

And generally ( slightly opinion based ) ; if you need to use `#pragma once` to make the code readable, it can ( and should ) be split into more function